# SimpleDraweeView was not initialized error using Fresco plugin in Nativescript Vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to implement Fresco in my NS Vue app.

I have this in my main.js

```
Vue.registerElement('FrescoDrawee', () => require("nativescript-fresco").FrescoDrawee)

var application = require("application");
var fresco = require("nativescript-fresco");

if (application.android) {
    application.onLaunch = function (intent) {
        fresco.initialize();
    };
}
```

and in home.vue

```
< FrescoDrawee horizontalAlignment="stretch" height="150" :imageUri="item.avatar" />
```

this is the error I'm getting. "SimpleDraweeView was not initialized!". I'm pretty sure the way I'm initializing it is wrong. Googling it gives me examples in TS and Angular, and none for nativescript Vue. any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly TypeScript is again JavaScript if you eliminate the typings from code. It's just the same you will have to follow in irrespective of your flavour (Core / Angular / Vue).

```
if (application.android) {
  application.on("launch", function () {
    fresco.initialize();
  });
}
```

Source: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-fresco#how-to-use-nativescript-fresco